# How to avoid race condition in php code

Tags: php, race-condition

I have good experience in Java/Java EE but I am very new to PHP. There is an small requirement where i want to share value of a variable(which contains a String token) 
accross different user requests. Now the issue is that i want to make the read and write of this variable thread safe i. at a time only one user can read/write 
in this variable.

If i was to do it in Java i would just take lock on a object by using synchonized keyword and can put the code block(read/write) in synchronzed block.

Here in PHP i have put the token in GLOBALS array but i am not getting any way by which i can made the read and write of this variable thread safe. I am avoiding
to use any external library to avoid depdency. Please guide me how this can be achived.

Comment: Where / how is the variable stored? PHP variables cease to exist when the script finishes so you'd need for example a file or a database to store the value.

Comment: I've not used Java for websites, but I think it's different from PHP in that sense that PHP scripts are shortlived and actually terminate at the end of the request. $_GLOBALS only provides access to variables in the currently running script. That run is only one thread. There can be other scripts running in parallel, but they have a completely separate scope. You can work with sessions, but that is for subsequent requests from a single user. If you want to share data between different requests of different users, I think the best options would be to use a file or a database.

Comment: if your system allows, then you can also try [Semaphore, Shared Memory and IPC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php) for inter-process communication

Answer (score 1):

You can use PECL pthreads. Which needs to be installed.

You can checkout the usage from:
http://php.net/manual/en/threaded.synchronized.php

Or the easier solution is to lock a file.

```
$fp = fopen("/tmp/lock.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // acquire an exclusive lock
    ftruncate($fp, 0);      // truncate file
    fwrite($fp, "Write something here\n");
    fflush($fp);            // flush output before releasing the lock
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock
} else {
    echo "Couldn't get the lock!";
}

fclose($fp);
```